# winrt-xaml syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

If this tag ([winrt-xaml](/questions/tagged/winrt-xaml)) is going to stay it should have an XML syntax highlighting hint. (Shouldn't this association be editable in the same way as a tag-wiki?)